There can't only be non-homogenous prime ideals between two homogenous primes. (Vakil 12.2.G, part c)
I'm stuck and looking for advice on part c of Question 12.2.G of Vakil's FOAG. The question states:
(a) Suppose $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is an irreducible projective $k$-variety. Show that the affine cone and projective cone over $X$ both have dimension $\text{dim}(X) + 1$.
(b) Show that a prime ideal of $k[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$ which is minimal over a homogeneous ideal is also homogeneous.
(c) Suppose $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathfrak{q}$ are two homogeneous prime ideals of $k[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$ such that there is no homogeneous prime ideal strictly between the two. Show that there is no prime ideal (not necessarily homogeneous) strictly between the two.
I tried to make use of the previous two parts of the problem, but the minimal prime ideal over $\mathfrak{p}$ should be $\mathfrak{p}$ itself, and I don't quite see how knowing the dimensions of $\text{Proj} (k[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]/\mathfrak{p})$ and $\text{Proj} (k[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]/\mathfrak{q})$ get me to the answer here.
I was also thinking about examining the homogenous elements of a hypothetical prime $\mathfrak{r}$ with $\mathfrak{p} \subsetneq \mathfrak{r} \subsetneq \mathfrak{q}$, but couldn't quite reach a contradiction there either (though this reasoning does show me that all of the homogenous elements in $\mathfrak{r}$ must be contained in $\mathfrak{p}$, or else they would form a homogenous ideal between $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$).


$\DeclareMathOperator{\Proj}{Proj}\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$I tried to make use of the previous two parts of the problem, but the minimal prime ideal over $\mathfrak{p}$ should be $\mathfrak{p}$ itself, and I don't quite see how knowing the dimensions of $\Proj (k[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]/\mathfrak{p})$ and $\Proj (k[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]/\mathfrak{q})$ get me to the answer here.

Since there is no homogeneous prime ideal between $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak q$, we know
$$\dim \Proj k[x_0, \dotsc, x_n] / \mathfrak p = 1 + \dim \Proj k[x_0, \dotsc, x_n]/ \mathfrak q.$$
By part (a), $\dim \Spec k[x_0, \dotsc, x_n]/\mathfrak p = 1 + \dim \Proj k[x_0, \dotsc, x_n]/\mathfrak p$, and similarly for $\mathfrak q$, so that
$$\dim \Spec k[x_0 , \dotsc, x_n] / \mathfrak p = 1 + \dim \Spec k[x_0, \dotsc, x_n] / \mathfrak q.$$
Hence there is no prime ideal between $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak q$.

To get that $\dim \operatorname{Proj} A/\mathfrak{p} = 1 + \dim \operatorname{Proj} A/\mathfrak{q}$, are you making use of the fact that $\operatorname{codim}_Z X = \dim X - \dim Z$ for $Z$ an irreducible closed subset of a variety $X$? ($A$ being the polynomial algebra)

@BrianShin Yes. Iirc, this boils down to polynomial algebras being catenary.

That makes sense. This equality and the notion of catenary-ness are introduced directly after this exercise in Vakil's notes, so I wonder if there's a way around this...
